# FloatingActionButton showing two colors (circles)

Tags: android, floating-action-button

I added a FloatingActionButton in the layout where its only parent is a CoordinatorLayout, so I don't understand where the backgroundTint color is coming from.

I tried to change the color to match the inner circle, but it changes the whole button to a solid color.

I also applied a different style, but it does not change the button at all.
I fixed this problem in the past, but I don't remember how I did it.

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/edit_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />
```

[image]

Comment: What is your desired color for FAB and inside icon? Gray FAB with crimson icon or reverse?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The gray color comes from your `colorAccent` defined for the app theme in `style.xml`. Now the `@drawable/ic_action_add` is a plus sign inside a filled circle. Try to use below icon instead:

**ic_add_black_24dp.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="M19,13h-6v6h-2v-6H5v-2h6V5h2v6h6v2z" />
</vector>
```

[image]

Then set a crimson color to the `FloatingActionButton`'s background tint and the gray one for icon tint:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/edit_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"
    app:tint="#404D54"
    app:backgroundTint="#6F303A"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp" />
```

---

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are not providing any `app:backgroundTint`, so it is using the default `colorAccent` from colors.xml.

**To solve this**:

1.Add a new color to colors.xml

```
<color name="fab_tint">#33d1ac</color>
```

2.Change the code as follows:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/edit_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"         
    app:backgroundTint="@color/fab_tint"/>
```